# Invoke-RestMethod returning 401 - Unauthorized in Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, invoke-restmethod

I'm running into an issue trying to use the Invoke-RestMethod command in PowerShell 7. I can get it to run fine in PowerShell 5.1, but 7 gives me a 401 - Unauthorized message.

Here's the command for PowerShell 5.1:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://internalServer/api/job?name=testJob" -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/JSON"
```

Here's the command for PowerShell 7:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://internalServer/api/job?name=testJob" -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/JSON" -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication
```

The api is hosted on an internal server that uses Windows Authentication. When I track the requests through Fiddler, both commands seem to get the 401 response, but PowerShell 5.1 uses the response to generate an Authorization: Negotiate YII{token} header whereas PowerShell 7 stops and returns an error. Has anyone else encountered this before?

Comment: There's no redirect going on is there?

Comment: Also, does it work in PS Core if you set `$env:DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER = 0`?

Comment: When they submit the first request, they both get a 301 response, the request that is made by the command after that is where they receive the 401 response.

Comment: Ah, I've got your solution then

Comment: I'm still getting the 401 error after changing the environment variable

Comment: You don't need to change the envvar. I wasn't sure whether you were hitting a different issue or if you had a redirect in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, there is a redirect going on here. By default, authentication won't survive a redirect, but you can control that with the `-PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect` parameter to [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1):

```
$irmParams = @{
  Uri = "http://internalServer/api/job?name=testJob"
  Method = 'GET'
  UseDefaultCredentials = $true
  ContentType = 'application/json'
  PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect = $true # <== Should be your solution
  AllowUnencryptedAuthentication = $true # <=== You should not be using this :)
}

Invoke-RestMethod @irmParams
```

---

[Thanks to some additional legwork by OP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate?view=netcore-3.1), `-PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect`:

> Will only keep the authentication headers for requests made to a `Uri` that includes the original `Uri` up to the last `/`. What the documentation doesn't include is that the subsequent `Uri`'s must also match the case of the original `Uri`.

In OP's case, the redirection was changing the case of the original `Uri`, thus breaking the authentication on redirect even when they specified `-PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect`.

Comment: It's still giving me the 401 error even when I include the MaximumRedirection parameter and bump it up to 10

Comment: Sorry I removed the `-MaximumRedirection` piece, bad intel. But `-PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect` is what you need.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with that parameter either.

Comment: After doing some deep digging into .NET Core's HttpWebRequest, I discovered that the PreAuthenticate property (which is what I think the PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect is using) will only keep the authentication headers for requests made to a uri that includes the original uri up to the last "/". 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate?view=netcore-3.1
What the documentation doesn't include is that the subsequent uri's must also match the case of the original uri. The redirect switches a part of the uri to lowercase where the original has upper

Comment: Ran out of space in the last comment. After changing the original uri to be lowercase, the PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect is now working. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks for that additional info, I meant to come back to this but it slipped my mind. I'll add your new information to my answer.

Comment: It makes sense that the `Uri` is case-sensitive here, which is juxtaposed against PowerShell's (usually) case-insensitive nature. While some web servers are case-insensitive, this is not a reliable assumption to make and so server names and paths must be considered case-sensitive in `Uri`s if we are to assume the same identity and path. I'm sure there is an RFC somewhere which dictates this as well..